# Zabbix-agent is not available for 3m docker

Tags: performance, docker-compose, monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

**I have installed zabbix-agent on a Linux server.  Changed IP address and hostname.
Then restart zabbix-agent. Seems to run**

```
 zabbix-agent.service - Zabbix Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-09-21 16:43:09 CEST; 16min ago
    Process: 511720 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c $CONFFILE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 511722 (zabbix_agentd)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 97584)
     Memory: 3.8M
        CPU: 339ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/zabbix-agent.service
             ├─511722 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
             ├─511723 "/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: collector [idle 1 sec]"
             ├─511724 "/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #1 [waiting for connection]"
             ├─511725 "/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #2 [waiting for connection]"
             ├─511726 "/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #3 [waiting for connection]"
             └─511727 "/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]"

Sep 21 16:43:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Zabbix Agent...
Sep 21 16:43:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Zabbix Agent.
```

but the agent does not connect to the server.
I get this

[image]

**could someone help ???
thanks**
**strong text**

Comment: you should check the agent log file for errors, then the server log file.

Answer (score 0):

The `Host name` is **Zabbix server** (case sensitive), in otherwords, there is a Zabbix Agent running in you Zabbix Server to monitoring it. You can see it in your image or in `Data collection` - `Hosts`.

This `Host Name` **MUST** the same that in `Hostname` line in `zabbix_agentd.conf` (or `ZBX_HOSTNAME` if you use a Zabbix Agent docker container). These need to match. So, in this file do:

1. Configure `Server` line to:

> Server=127.0.0.1 # or Zabbix Server IP/hostname

2. Configure `Hostname` line to:

> Hostname=Zabbix server # literal

and restart the Zabbix Agent service.

If this doesn't work, in Zabbix Web Interface:

1. go to `Data collection` - `Hosts`
2. click in the Name of host
3. configure the `Dns name` to your host name (the hostname that **Zabbix Agent** knows) and select `DNS`
4. You can see more details in [Zabbix forum](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/465133-new-test-setup-docker-compose-agent-not-running?p=465183#post465183)